# Does INVOKERS rights mean the DB session initiator or the user calling the Procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

We have an application running on Oracle APEX (ORDS) workspace with parsing schema as "SCHEMA_A"

I have a package "**PKG_A1**" in schema "**SCHEMA_A**".

I have a package "**PKG_B1**" in schema "**SCHEMA_B**".

I have another package "**PKG_B2**" in schema "**SCHEMA_B**" and that package has **AUTHID CURRENT_USER** clause.

As we know **APEX_PUBLIC_USER** initiate the session, The call from application to PKG_B2 happens as below:

**PKG_A1 --> PKG_B1 --> PKG_B2**.

Note: grant execute ON PKG_B1 to schema_A

**Question 1:** **PKG_B2 is executed with SCHEMA_A rights or SCHEMA_B rights or APEX_PUBLIC_USER rights?**

Also, if SCHEMA_B has a table "TABLE_B1" exists and a public synonym of a view with the name "TABLE_B1" exists and

PKG_B2 has call to "TABLE_B1" without user alias.

**Question 2: will the synonym be called or table is called when called from application?**

Please help clarify this

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1: PKG_B2 is executed with SCHEMA_A rights or SCHEMA_B rights or APEX_PUBLIC_USER rights?**

**Answer 1:**

As far as I follow you, You want to know if PKG_B2 will be called using SCHEMA_A rights.

It means PKG_A1 --> PKG_B1 --> PKG_B2 will be executed with the following rights respectively.

```
PKG_A1(SCHEMA_A) --> PKG_B1(SCHEMA_B) --> PKG_B2(SCHEMA_A)
```

**Question 2: will the synonym be called or table is called when called from the application?**

**Answer 2:**

Table from SCHEMA_B is called.

Comment: Because PKG_B2 is an invoker's right package shouldn't it inherit the schema_b rights because its invoked by PKG_B1 who has already inherited SCHEMA_B (because of definers rights). If we assume the invoker here is the first user who initiated the call stack even then it would be APEX_PUBLIC_USER and not SCHEMA_A right?

Comment: Also, if PKG_B2 is run as SCHEMA_A, since the table is being called without user alias nd no object with same table name in schema_a shouldn't the call move to the public synonym?